# How to integrate ratio of summations $\int_0^1 \sum_{i=0}^{2n} x^{i} /\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^{i}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} x^{i}}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} x^{i}} \, dx$$
I am trying this question by applying the expansions of $$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} x^{i}$$ and $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^{i}$$
The expansion of the 1st geometric series is $$\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}$$
and the expansion of the 2nd geometric series is $$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
So, the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx$$
But, I can't proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: Try expanding $\dfrac1{1-x^{n+1}}$ as a series, then interchange the integral with summation. You should end up with some kind of polygamma expression.

Comment: Please show me the full solution.

Answer (score 7):

As you've shown, the integral reduces to

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx$$

Exploiting series, we can write this as

$$I_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(x^{k(n+1)} - x^{k(n+1)+2n+1}\right) \, dx = \frac1{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{k+\frac1{n+1}} - \frac1{k+2}\right)$$

Now use the series expansion for the digamma function,

$$\psi(z) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{k+1} - \frac1{k+z}\right),$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, as well as the relation $\psi(z+1)=\psi(z)+\dfrac1z$ to evaluate the sum and we end up with

$$I_n = \frac{1 - \gamma - \psi\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)}{n+1}$$

Some exact values of $I_n$ can be easily found using known forms of the digamma term listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

Using $$ \sum_{i=0}^nx^i=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I_n &=& \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx\overset{x^{n+1}\to x}=\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{-\frac{n}{n+1}}-x}{1-x}dx\\
&=&\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)-(1-x^{-\frac{n}{n+1}})}{1-x}dx\\
&=&\frac1{n+1}\bigg(1-H_{-\frac{n}{n+1}}\bigg)\\
&=& \frac{1 - \gamma - \psi\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)}{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
The last line uses the result
$$ H_x=\psi(1+x)+\gamma $$
from [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#:~:text=Harmonic%20numbers%20are%20related%20to,the%20first%20n%20positive%20integers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#:%7E:text=Harmonic%20numbers%20are%20related%20to,the%20first%20n%20positive%20integers).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elementary solution. Note that

\begin{align}
I_n = &\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx\\
=& \int_0^1 x^n +\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx
=\frac1{1+n}+ \int_0^1\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x^{n+1}} dx
\end{align}
Then, per partial fractions with $a_k=\frac{2\pi k}{1+n}$
\begin{align}
&(1+n)\int\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x^{n+1}}dx\\
=&\int \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1-x\cos a_k}{1-2x \cos a_k +x^2}-\frac{(1+n)x^n}{1-x^{n+1}}\bigg) dx\\
=& \ \ln\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg(\frac{\ln(1-2x\cos a_k +x^2)}{2\sec a_k}+ \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{\sin a_k}{x-\cos a_k}}{\csc a_k}\bigg)\\
\end{align}
Apply the integral bounds, along with
$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sin a_k=-\pi \cot \frac\pi{1+n}$, to obtain
$$I_n=\frac1{1+n}\left[1+\ln[2(1+n)]+\frac\pi2\cot \frac\pi{1+n}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln(\sin\frac{\pi k}{1+n})}{\sec \frac{2\pi k}{1+n}}\right]
$$
Listed below are some examples of the close-form result:
\begin{align}
I_1 =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^3}{1-x^2}dx=&\frac12+\ln2\\
I_2 =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^5}{1-x^3}dx=&\frac13+\frac12\ln3 +\frac\pi{6\sqrt3}\\
 I_3 =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^7}{1-x^4}dx=&\frac14+\frac34\ln2+\frac\pi{8}\\
 I_4 =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^9}{1-x^5}dx=&\frac15+\frac15\ln10+\frac\pi{10}\cot\frac\pi5\\
& -\frac{2\ln(\sin\frac\pi5)}{5\sec \frac{2\pi}5}
-\frac{2\ln(\sin\frac{2\pi}5)}{5\sec \frac{4\pi}5}\\
I_5 =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x^6}dx=&\frac16+\frac13\ln2+\frac14\ln3+\frac\pi{4\sqrt3}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comments.*

Up to $n=3$, using partial fraction decomposition, the integrals are very easy to compute.

You already received the answers for any $n$
$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}} \, dx=\frac{1 - \gamma - \psi\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)}{n+1}$$ Expanding as series
$$I_n=1+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6 (n+1)^2}+\frac{\zeta (3)}{(n+1)^3}-\frac{\pi
   ^4}{90 (n+1)^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ is extremely accurate even for small $n>4$.

**Edit**

As @AaronHendrickson commented
$$I_n=1+\frac{1}{n+1}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{\zeta(k)}{(n+1)^k}$$

Comment: Its interesting that$$I_n\sim 1+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{\zeta (3)}{(n+1)^3}-\frac{\zeta(4)}{(n+1)^4}$$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. It is not $\color{red}{\sim}$ but  $\color{red}{=}$. Thanks for the comment, stranger.